Bounding an equivalent expression of Mertens function
Some months ago, I derived the following formula for the Merten's function $M(n)$ using the inclusion-exclusion principle:
$$M(n)=1-\pi\left(n\right)+\sum_{p_{i}\leq\frac{n}{p_i}}\left(\pi\left(\frac{n}{p_{i}}\right)-i\right)-\sum_{p_{i}<p_{j}\leq\frac{n}{p_ip_j}}\left(\pi\left(\frac{n}{p_{i}p_{j}}\right)-j\right)+\sum_{p_{i}<p_{j}<p_{k}\leq\frac{n}{p_ip_jp_k}}\left(\pi\left(\frac{n}{p_{i}p_{j}p_{k}}\right)-k\right)-\dots$$
This expression can be reformulated more elegantly (as proposed by @StevenClark in this previous question I posted some time ago) as
$$M(x)=1 - \sum\limits_{Gpf(k)\leq \frac{x}{k}} \mu(k)\left(\pi\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)- \pi(Gpf(k)\right)$$
In both expressions we have that $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function. In the second expression we have that $Gpf(x)$ is the greatest prime factor of $x$.
I have tried to derive something insightful from the above equivalence to bound $M(x)$ sharply, but unsuccessfully. I even do not know if either $\sum\limits_{Gpf(k)\leq \frac{x}{k}} \mu(k) \pi\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)$ or $\sum\limits_{Gpf(k)\leq \frac{x}{k}} \mu(k) \pi(Gpf(k))$ can be bounded sharply using Möbius inversion or some other technique.
I would appreciate any answer addressing (i) the possibility to extract valuable information from the expression in order to bound $M(x)$, and / or (ii) showing techniques that could potentially lead to bound the whole main expression or any of the sub-expressions.
I include a graph plotting both $\sum\limits_{Gpf(k)\leq \frac{x}{k}} \mu(k) \pi\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)$ and $\sum\limits_{Gpf(k)\leq \frac{x}{k}} \mu(k) \pi(Gpf(k))$, and including $\sqrt{x}$ and $-\sqrt{x}$:

Thanks in advance for your help!
